# Why isn't datatypes showing in blue color in vscode

Tags: dart, visual-studio-code

Why here the int variable is not showing in blue color like the class Transaction color in blue mentioned above.
And its a .dart file for your clarity

[image: Here is the written code]

Comment: This doesn't really have to do with the Dart language, or VSCode in particular. Rather, it's simply a matter of your syntax highlighting theme. You can change your theme by bringing up the command palette and typing "color theme" - there you can browse the themes you've installed, or search themes in the marketplace.

Comment: @MichaelHorn I think it's all about Dart and to some extent the code editor too. The question is (or it seems to, at least) about why those elements have different colors and it's all about how they're classified in the language and interpreted by the editor. It's not asking something like "how to make that red instead of blue" that would have been solved by a theme.

Answer (score 0):

There is a small difference between the two. `class` is a reserved keyword and the data types are types, and as such qualify differently to the code editor.

The `class` is a reserved language word and is painted as blue here. This includes every other special word that has a particular meaning to the language.

All other are identifier for data types. `int`, `String` and all others, even though they're built-in to the language, are used here as a data type that qualifies the identifier they're attached to, and as such have the green coloring in your case. Note that it's the same color as `Transaction` here, as this is a class definition and a class defines a (custom) type too.

Answer (score 0):

`class` is a [keyword](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#keywords). `int` is a [type](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#built-in-types) - in fact, since everything is an object in Dart, [`int` is also a class](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.16.1/dart-core/int-class.html), just like `Transaction` that you defined, so it makes sense to have the same color.

<sub>And if you really, really think this is wrong, you could always [open an issue](https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code/issues) about it with the author of the Dart extension.</sub>